# Реверс инжиниринг

Tags: c++, qt, файлы, reverse-engineering, binary-file

Доброго времени суток!

Есть бинарный файл, формат которого не известен. Вместе с этим есть данные, которые этот файл содержит, но уже в текстовом виде. Суть задачи состоит в том, чтобы понять в каком формате хранятся данные. Нужен гайд или хотя бы набор советов, как подступиться к такой проблеме и что в первую очередь проверить.

Данные в текстовом формате из этого бинарного файла умеет доставать программа, написанная на Qt. Может имеет смысл попробовать декомпилировать эту программу, но тогда каким образом найти то место в коде, в котором этот файл читается?

Comment: данные хранятся в бинарном формате. Другого ответа нет.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan неужели нет способа выяснить формат хотя бы отдельных частей файла?

Comment: Проверьте, не является ли бинарный файл одним из стандартных иерархических контейнеров: зипованным xml , hdf5, или контейнером OLE. Если нет - то нет.

Comment: Для начала надо проверить заголовок, header файла. МАгическое число, то есть первые несколько букв. По ним можно понять что-за файл. МОжет это вообще elf формат для линукса.  Если нет заголовка, то скорее всего код начинается с самого начала.

Comment: @Chorkov а как это можно сделать? Просто поменять расширение файла и попробовать открыть архиватором? Или есть специальные инструменты для таких целей?

Comment: @Asem просто попытаться открыть архиватором (даже не меня расширения). Обычно, они автоматом пробуют несколько форматов.

Comment: Можно попробовать команду [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file)

Answer (score 2):

Как просили, немного сумбурный набор советов

1. Стоит попытаться открыть файл любым шестнадцатеричным редактором. Первое что я пробую делать - открываю файл в стандартном просмотрщике Тотал Коммандера (горячая клавиша F3). Это позволяет сразу увидеть, есть ли в файле текстовые данные, например. Как уже посоветовали в комментариях - можно попробовать открыть файл архиватором.
2. Можно загнать бинарный файл в IDA Pro (достаточно даже бесплатной версии) и попробовать вручную разметить данные. Изначально все выглядит как массив байт с комментариями там где байт попадает в символьный диапазон.

   - На том что похоже на текст жмем `a` - если это ascii, а не юникод. Если не ascii, но явно текст - жмем `alt+a` и выбираем нужную кодировку.
   - На том что похоже на 4-байтные целые числа (например) - три раза жмем `d` (для однобайтных значений 1 раз, для двухбайтных - 2 раза). В общем, базовые умения пользоваться Идой пригодятся.
3. Пробуем загонять программу-конвертер в IDA Pro, открываем таблицу импорта, ищем функции связанные с открытием файлов, смотрим ссылки на них (xrefs - cross-references), по одной из (сотни) этих ссылок будет код открытия интересующего вас файла (и иногда просмотр сотни ссылок приносит нужный результат). Также можно поискать функцию диалогового окна открытия файла.

   - В целом, если вы работали с Qt, то названия функций (методов) должны будут вам что-то говорить (если конечно библиотека Qt не прилинкована статически).
   - Если есть какой-то текст, выводящийся на экран сразу после загрузки файла или до нее - можно пробовать искать в исполняемом файле его, потом опять же по ссылкам на этот текст переходим на код, который на него ссылается. Нужно быть готовым к тому, что декомпилятор вам скорее всего никак не поможет, поэтому нужно хотя бы на каком-то базовом уровне знать ассемблер.
   - Это общий принцип - ищем то, за что можно зацепиться (известную функцию или текст), от этого возвращаемся в код.
   - Это все при условии если экзешник ничем не упакован и не зашифрован - для новичка это будет практически непреодолимым препятствием.

Answer (score 1):

Скачайте любой редактор бинарных файлов, например https://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor. В таких редакторах есть возможность поиска стандартных числовых типов (int, short, float, double и т.д.) и текстовых строк. Ищите числа или строки, которые там точно есть (Вы их знаете из имеющегося у Вас текстового представления). На бумажке рисуете структуру хранения информации в файле и думаете, как дальше с ней работать. Но все это сработает только если файл не сжат, не зашифрован и еще как-нибудь не модифицирован.